# Power bi embedded visuals performance. Slow loading

Tags: javascript, asp.net, api, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am developing a webportal where I am using embedded power bi visuals, but they are loading really slow. I have 16 visuals in one pageview and it will take 10-25 seconds for them all to load.

Is this normal? Can I do anything to make it load faster? Is query caching useful? Are there any downsides by using query caching?

This is how I embed my visuals:

```
let embedConfiguration = {
                                   accessToken: "@ViewBag.Token",
                                   embedUrl: "@ViewBag.EmbedUrl",
                                   id: "@ViewBag.Id",
                                   pageName: pageName,
                                   tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
                                   type: 'visual',
                                   visualName: visualName,
                               };
                                
                               // Get a reference to the HTML element that contains the embedded report.
                               let embedContainer = $('#'+embedContainerName)[0];
                               
                               // Embed the visual.
                               let visual = await powerbi.embed(embedContainer, embedConfiguration);
```

Since I have up to 16 visuals per page I add them all to a list, where I store the page name, visual name, and container name (id of the divs to embed the visual in).
Then I run the list through a for-loop that does the embedding as shown in the code above. This function is async, so it doesn't load 1 by 1 visual.
Are there other ways to do this that will make it load the visuals quicker?

Comment: I would compare the load time of each visual to the load times running on the service.  A page in the service will also load all visuals in asynchronously.  Do you have the option to load an entire page rather than individual visuals?

Comment: When I open the report in app.powerbi, it loads very quickly. If that is what you meant?
It needs to be individual visuals to fit in the design that is proposed. However, it might be possible to group some visuals and embed those as one iframe instead? I am not familiar with the possibilities in power bi, so I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: This is an example of how it's embedded: https://imgur.com/a/ocyIVOd
Where V = individual Visual.
If I understand you correct, what you are suggesting is to add for example the first row of visuals to one page, and instead embed the entire page?

Comment: If the report loads quickly in app.powerbi, then the issue is something with the embedded call and query caching is not going to help out.  I would try loading a whole report page, which should take about the same amount of time is app.powerbi.  If it still takes as long as loading the visuals individually, we'll know it's some other issue - network or app code.

Comment: Embedding a single report or a single page is very quick. Same if I only embed a few visuals, it will load fast. When embedding 10 visuals it took about 8 seconds. When embedding more than this, and with visuals being further down on the webpage, the loading slows down drastically. 5 visuals took about 5 seconds to load from when I clicked the link that redirects me to the page containing the visuals till them being finished loading.

Comment: Check if this is relevant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-performance-best-practices#multiple-visuals Can you reduce the number of iFrames that you are using?

Comment: I saw this but didn't really understand how you can embed multiple visuals in 1 iframe. As of now, I'm using 1 iFrame per visual, but I'm guessing it is possible to create a power bi page where I include, let's say all these visuals in row1 from my example earlier: imgur.com/a/ocyIVOd, and then just embedding that page into 1 iFrame? That would mean the styling of the layout would have to be done in power bi for these visuals grouped in that page?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  I would give it a go in the simplest way, before bothering with the formatting, to see if it makes any difference

Comment: I'm gonna give that a go when I have the chance! I think that would be my best bet to reduce the loading time. Thanks a lot, Mark!